# In an ExtJS Grid's actioncolumn, how do I make use of the `v` parameter that's passed to getClass/getTip?

Tags: extjs

In an ExtJS grid, I have an `actioncolumn` that I want to have a different icon/tooltip based on the data in the row (actually, within a particular column of the row).

The first parameter to the `getClass` and `getTip` callbacks is `v`, described in the documentation as:

> The value of the column's configured field (if any).

I have defined my `actioncolumn` as follows, specifying the 'configured field' using the `dataIndex` property:

```
    {
        xtype: "actioncolumn",
        flex: 0.25,
        dataIndex: "action_name",  // Defines which field should be passed in as v, below
        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
            // v is "", yet r.get("action_name") is "Capture Fill"
        }
    });
```

Within the `getClass` callback, I'm able to access the value of the *action_name* field through `r.get("action_name")`, but v is `""`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `Column` can be configured (for some column types it must be configured) with [dataIndex](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action-cfg-dataIndex) cfg. `dataIndex` tells column which field of the model to use while rendering.

If you configure your ActionColumn with `dataIndex` config you will be able to use the value of corresponding model's field in `getClass` and `getTip` callbacks.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/vdvv8/) (see the output in console).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I've set the dataIndex now, but I still always get `v == ""`. I've revised my question.

Comment: @DanielFortunov, You probably have forgotten to add `action_name` to the `fields` config of your store/model. See the demo.

Comment: @DanielFortunov, Oh I see where the bug is. `getClass` should be specified as a config of column's item(button).

Comment: Hmm, wait, what's the difference? The actioncolumn has a getClass config; I figured the intent was that if you are only going to have one item in the items collection then as a short-cut you can just use getClass directly on the actioncolumn and it would behave the same. Is that wrong?

Comment: @DanielFortunov, this seems to be logical. But as you can see it just doesn't work this way.

Comment: Except that, yes, it does work that way. I removed the items collection and moved `icon` and `getClass` up to the parent `actioncolumn` and your sample code works exactly the same. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/YYuMP/ Unfortunately in my code it doesn't work either way -- `v` is always `""` Not sure what I'm doing differently :-(